# Azure Data Factory Scheduled Triggers Not Working

Tags: triggers, scheduler, azure-data-factory

I tried to setup scheduled triggers within Azure Data Factory, but they are not getting executed and are not logged either. They used to work but since a couple of days nothing happens anymore, even when I delete them and setup new ones.

When I hit "trigger now", everything is fine.
So basically I setup scheduled triggers (activate them), deploy them and wait for the automatic call but nothing happens at all.

Do you have an idea?

[lot of configured triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsRtM.png)
[emtpy trigger execution logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2S95.png)

eg:

```
{
"name": "Trigger_Hourly3",
"properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "runtimeState": "Started",
    "pipelines": [
        {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "Pipe_02_xy",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Hour",
            "interval": 1,
            "startTime": "2020-06-30T13:43:00.000Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks, Lukas

Comment: Did you check the trigger in Portal?

Comment: Yes, I checked the trigger it was set to "Started" in the ADF UI, but querying from PowerShell it was "Stopped". So I started it again through PS and it turned out to be stopped after next deployment. I then went to Azure DevOps Release Log where I saw that there is a unsucccessfull deployment (despite sending back a success event to ADF), preventing the following trigger activation task to get executed. Once I fixed the deployment error, the step with the script to restart triggers was executed again and everything worked smoothly again! Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution: Fixed an error that was raised during Azure DevOps deployment that was not raised by ADF validation and not sent back as error to ADF UI. Then the triggers were activated again in the following task and everything runs smoothly again.